Windows Server gets IP address via DHCP for too long
I don't know if I specified the correct title, but the point is that Windows Server tries to get an IP address within 2-3 seconds. But at the moment when the lease renewal occurs, the server has no IP address and all active connections are broken. There are two network interfaces on the server. The first one is for the Internet, it has a public IP, the second one is for the local network, it has a subnet 192.168.0.0/24. I was able to catch the problem at the right moment
C:\Users\****>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::872e:6462:53ff:f677%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 11.22.33.44
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 11.22.33.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::587d:df21:3c87:6a9a%17
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

And after a few seconds:
C:\Users\****>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::872e:6462:53ff:f677%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 11.22.33.44
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 11.22.33.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::587d:df21:3c87:6a9a%17
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :


Ubuntu Server, which is located on the same local network, does not have this problem.

I don't understand the problem you're describing. Could you elaborate?

"But at the moment when the lease renewal occurs, the server has no IP address and all active connections are broken." - this is NOW how DHCP works, it is not how it is supposed to work. The server should try to renew after HALF the lease time, which means PLENTY time left. Also, the server should NOT discard the IP address "just because". You give ZERO information how to debug this - because the error is in the information you do not give. Definitely look at the  DHCP Server. Start debugging - or hire an admin
